# Overlaying image also fades when images change in IE6 jQ slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a pretty basic slideshow fading between images. On top of that slideshow I have a logo that is absolute positioned to stay partly over the slideshow. It works perfectly, but then there is IE6. In IE6  the part of the logo that is overlaying the slideshow also fades when the images change in the slideshow.

I really do not want to have half the logo in all the pictures in the slideshow, but that seems to be the only solution right now.

Demo of the problem here: http://nonstopas.no/temp/slideshow/

Note that this happens a bit inconsistently (or so it seems), so watch it for a couple of rounds.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Displays fine in my IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resolve the issue by using the bgiframe, but setting the z-index on the logo to a high value (300) did the  trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the bgiframe plugin works. I have used this before to fix the z-index of objects over dropdowns but it works for this too.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe

I was able to replicate and solve your issue on my own version of your test page in IE6.